# Make a bootstrap list look like a multiselect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and I'd like to leverage their pleasant list formatting.  However, I'm trying to create a single-page site and the length of the list is breaking things badly because there are too many items and the containing element extends downward past the bottom of the screen.  The containing element is constrained at 30% of the total screen height, rather than an absolute px.

What I would really like is a control that acts like a `<select multiple="true">`-type control, but with bootstrap styling.  Naturally, bootstrap recommendations are not to use the select/option tags because they don't take cross-browser styling well.

I've tried to force a list to a certain height, but keep hitting walls of various types.  When I first tried to use SCSS to calculate the height I would actually want (H2 + the height of three `<li>`'s), I found myself unable to figure out what all of the bootstrap variables were relevant.  When I tried setting the parent element to `overflow-y:scroll`, the whole element scrolls, where I only want the list portion to scroll.  Finally, just trying to attach bootstrap classes to a select/option list didn't work, which was probably foreseeable.

Any help, including redirecting to a better design is useful.

Comment: Hey there, unfortunately without seeing the code you're working with we'll be flying blind. Can you re-create your issue in a jsfiddle (or even provide the link to the site)?

Comment: Off topic, but you shouldn't write `<select multiple="true">`. The [W3C page on boolean attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) explicitly states, *The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.*

Comment: Mr Lister- yeah, I know.  I've always had that discussion more commonly from the other direction i.e. people try to write `<select multiple="false">` and get annoyed when it appears as a multiselect.  You're technically correct (the best kind of correct) though, the boolean is unnecessary and bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem became more clear as I dug deeper.  The issue was actually that I was setting an explicit height on the wrong element.  I was trying to set a percentage height on my list without having set it on my containing div.

Once I explicitly set height of the containing div AND the list to 100%, then set `overflow-y:scroll`, I got the outcome I wanted.